# Concatenate with variable in jquery append-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

How could i concatenate a variable in the append-function in jquery?

I have a loop where I dynamically creates checkboxes in a html-table. And every checkbox needs a unique id since I attach a listener to each of them after the loop.

What I want is to add the increment variable in the for loop (variable i)
so in every loop the id is concatenated with variable i that is

loop 0, name should be cb0
loop 1, name should be cb1
and so on..

here is what I've tried

```
$('<td valign="top"></td>').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"cb\" ' + cnt + '>').appendTo(row);
```

where cnt is the variable that increments with an integer in each loop

Something is wrong with the concatenation here - greatful for help

Comment: How about providing a demo/fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have closed the quote early i.e. it is not adding the cnt variable.

Try

```
$('<td valign="top"></td>').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"cb' + cnt + '\">').appendTo(row);
```

Instead of

```
$('<td valign="top"></td>').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"cb\" ' + cnt + '>').appendTo(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your output at all?

This code:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id=\"cb\" ' + cnt + '>'
```

Would produce this output:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" 1>
```

That errant `1` has no relation to the `id` value.  Instead, include it as part of the value.  You can also remove the `\` characters, since you don't need to escape quotes here:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="cb' + cnt + '">'
```

Which would produce:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```
$("<td>", {
   valign: "top",
   html: "<input type=checkbox id=cb" + cnt + ">"
}).appendTo(row);
```